# Не могу воспроизвести аудио

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь воспроизвести песню, но играет только первые 3 секунды... В
   чем может быть проблема ? В Java нет опыт. Пытаюсь сделать музыкальный плеер как первый проект (Может кто, какой совет дополнительно даст)

```
package sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


        String path = "C://Users/m4med/Desktop/linkin_park_-_numb.mp3";

        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);


        primaryStage.setTitle("Playing Audio");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После завершения метода `start` ссылка на `MediaPlayer` больше никому не нужна и, видимо, сборщик мусора уничтожает объект. Вынесите объявление за пределы метода:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ...
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    ...
}
```

А так для `mp3` наверное больше подходит [AudioClip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html).

Comment: Помогло, спасибо !
Буду пробовать через AudioClip